# Android handling multiple button clicks

Tags: android

So I have a button that initiates communication to a server. However, when I try to disable the button from within the on click (to stop multiple clicks) it doesn't happen until the on click ends. This is a problem as the server communication means it takes a while for the method to execute. I saw a previous question that was answered by using flags to stop the multiple clicks (and it was stated that it is a known bug that buttons cannot be immediately inactivated). Is there now any other more elegant solution to this problem or is flags still the only way?

Answer (score 3):

in Button's `onClick()`

You can,

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

what is did when I had this problem is use a boolean flag for this, here is a sample code for using a flag:

```
boolean isClicked = false;
Button btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if (!isClicked) {
           isClicked = true;
           // CONNECT TO SERVER
           isClicked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the button,

```
button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

or Disable the button

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

or Keep a flag using boolean